# Laravel 5.2 AWS S3 Bucket image upload Error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, filesystems, laravel-5.1

I want to upload my image files into my s3 bucket.but got error

my code

```
$image = $request->file('photo_one');
$imageFileName = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
$s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
$filePath = '/products/' . $imageFileName;
$s3->put($filePath, file_get_contents($image), 'public');
```

My File System Configuration

```
's3' => [
    'driver' => 's3',
    'key'    => 'xxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxx',
    'region' => 'Oregon',
    'bucket' => 'xxxxx',
],
```

I am getting error

```
        Error executing "PutObject" on "https://s3.Oregon.amazonaws.com
    /xxx/1455525865.jpeg"; AWS HTTP error: cURL 
error 6: Could not resolve host: s3.Oregon.amazonaws.com
    (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

Answer (score 1):

as per my understanding, you are not using the proper region for your bucket. You cannot use `Oregon`, follow this link, find the exact region for your bucket located in. [AWS Regions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html)

**Edited**
eg: try this region     `us-west-2`